# spring Rest json response format

Tags: json, spring

i am dealing with a spring project and stuck with rest json response format.
what i can get is as following:

```
"data" : [ {
    "type" : "xx",
    "properties" : "xx",
    "price" : "xx",
    "storeAddress" : "xx"
  }, {
    "type" : "xxx",
    "properties" : "xxx",
    "price" : "xxx",
    "storeAddress" : "xxx"
  }]
}
```

and what i really want is there is new line at the begin of each object in list so it looks as following:

```
"data" : [ 
          {
            "type" : "xx",
            "properties" : "xx",
            "price" : "xx",
            "storeAddress" : "xx"
          }, 
          {
            "type" : "xxx",
            "properties" : "xxx",
            "price" : "xxx",
            "storeAddress" : "xxx"
          }
          ]
    }
```

is there any simple way as configuring feature in application.properties file?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @sonus21,  there is "changing line"  before each object.